# Does QGIS support HTML5 and CSS3?

Tags: qgis, css, html5, design

I know that I can put HTML and CSS, and QGIS will render such code but some CSS styles like grid and pseudo-selectors are not working. Thus I wanted to know what level of support is there especially for the newer web standards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on your QGIS version and the Qt toolkit version it's based on. First look into *Help > About* to retrieve the Qt version. If you are referring to a print layout, QGIS uses *QWebView* (HTML frame items - QgsLayoutItemHtml) and *QWebPage*
widgets (HTML label items - QgsLayoutItemLabel) to render HTML. When I look into the source code (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/) I can find references of QTextBrowser (QgsWebView) and QTextDocument (QgsTextAnnotation) as well that only support a limited subset of HTML4: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html

Maybe @NyallDawson can jump in and give a detailed answer?

Comment: For which parts is QWebView used and for which parts QLabel?

Comment: @Matthias good question, I'm sure you know the right answer :-) QWebView is used for all HTML frames, and QLabel was a pure guess of mine (for Label items). Maybe you could show us how to retrieve the Qt widget class names from the QGIS widgets?

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/ ;-)

With respect to your answer, I think the question needs clarification *where* in QGIS it is asking for. Inside your answer the link could be put in context (does it apply for labels or web view)